# How do I a convert a number to an INTERVAL of minutes?

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

In pseudo-Oracle, I want to do the following:

```
select systimestamp + to_interval(select NUMERIC_COLUMN from SOME_TABLE where SOME_TABLE_PK = :stuff) from dual;
```

If the number of minutes were always the same, I could use an interval literal a la `interval '360' minute`, but I can't find a simple function to convert a number to a `MINUTE` interval. What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [numtodsinterval](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions103.htm#i88258) function which does exactly the conversion you need (number to interval):

```
SQL> select systimestamp, systimestamp + numtodsinterval(20, 'MINUTE') from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP              SYSTIMESTAMP+NUMTODSINTERVAL(2
------------------------- -------------------------------
2011-08-22 16:12:24.060   2011-08-22 16:32:24.060
```